# How can we use built-in jmeter functions in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I seem to have spent far too long trying to discover a way to obtain information such as the `machineName` I'd like to use https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html in two different programming languages, in Groovy code (rather than BeanShell, etc), and in Java.

In groovy, I have tried using `ctx`, `vars`, and `props` to no avail.

Similarly it'd be great to discover how to do the same in a Java Sampler. From what I can tell I can get some information e.g. the thread number using `JMeterContextService.getContext().getThreadNum()` but I've not found a way to interact/use the main JMeter functions.

One way might be to re-implement the functions, especially where they're described e.g. "The machineName function returns the local host name. This uses the Java method `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` and passes it to `getHostName()`" but I hope that's not necessary...

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The best option is putting the function call to "Parameters" section and refer its return value as `Parameters` or `args[0]` in script body like

   ```
   def machineName = Parameters
   ```

   [image: JMeter Function via Parameters]
2. You can do it via instance of [MachineName class](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/functions/MachineName.html) like:

   ```
   def machineName = new org.apache.jmeter.functions.MachineName().compute()
   ```
3. You can do it using [JMeterUtils](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html) helper class like:

   ```
   def machineName = org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostName()
   ```
4. And finally (but this is not recommended as caching of compiled scripts won't be available) you can inline any JMeter function into script body

   ```
   def machineName = '${__machineName()}'
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you, particularly as I now realise how to call inbuilt functions in various ways & some of the tradeoffs. It's a pity there aren't equivalent short methods similar to vars, props, etc. for these methods.